# Generate random numbers between a range with only two decimal points in python

Tags: python

I wish to Generate random numbers between a range with only two decimal points in python.

For example I need to generate
Range(100,200)

And output should be 102.33 or 130.42

Just any random number with only 2 decimal point.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] t include a [mcve] showing _code_ for what you've tried so far, and a description of what went wrong with your attempts

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint

def randbetween(x, y):
    return randint(x*100, y*100)/100

randbetween(100,200) #127.12
```